# Datagrip - table names do not appear when clicking on schema names in left-hand panel

Tags: datagrip

I recently installed Datagrip to view my Company's Postgres database, however I am currently unable to view the tables in the different schemas by clicking on the schema name:

[image: Screenshot image of hierarchy]

In the image, I've clicked to open and show the `ab-testing` schema, however nothing appears below it. This behavior is consistent across all of the schemas in the database. I am able to use the query editor to query tables in the schemas (assuming i know the table names), yet I cannot see the names in the left-side panel. I am using datagrip 2020.2

Thanks!

Comment: I am able to click to open schemas / see its tables in a 2nd database we have in datagrip. However, for the database and schema I need to see, I cannot open it up

Comment: Refresh doesn't help?

Comment: Could you also to execute any query against `ab-testing` scheme via DataGrip console?

Answer (score 2):

Right click Microsoft SQL Server in the left pane in Datagrip, then go to "Properties", then"Schemas". Find your database and make sure "All schemas" is ticked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a MySQL database. As a test, I used the MariaDB driver instead of the MySQL driver as usual. This was intentional and not an oversight, but it was not a good idea!

The tables, views and server objects were not displayed. Although I was able to display the tables and views after activating Schema Properties -> Advanced -> "Introspect using JDBC metadata", the server objects were not displayed. Working with the displayed tables and views was not possible in the usual way.

Only when I used the MySQL driver again, everything worked correctly again. The tables, views and server objects were displayed correctly and the work with it was possible in the usual way.

As a small quintessence I would like to recommend to all who "struggle" with similar problems to check your chosen drivers. Maybe the problem is caused by choosing the wrong driver, as it was in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Whick kind of message do you get when instrospecting the schema?
I had a `java.io.CharConversionException` caused by a not valid UTF-8 string.
If this is the case, you can add the following VM option `-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issues and here is my solution and it's work!
(Previously I tried to use **Force Refresh** but it didn't work and then I found this solution accidentally)

Solution:
Try to create a new table with a duplicate name from **Database Explorer** by following these steps.

1. Right-clicking on your not-shown table schema then ***New -> Table***. [Step 1 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnGDD.png)
2. Fill the table_name with the existing table name on your schema. Then, try to click **OK** about 3-4 times. [Step 2 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPVku.png)
3. Then, click **Cancel** and close the panel. [Step 3 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cILl5.png)
4. Your data sources will refresh and the list of tables will come! [Step 4 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL0eF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the "folder" and click "refresh". This has got to be done on the specific folder and not any of it's parents. So drill down to where clicking the chevron doesn't open anything and click "refresh" on that.

[image]